Why is the BIOS designed to be near 0xFFFFF instead of 0xF0000?
I am currently doing an experiment for S6.828 and I am facing a problem.
+------------------+  <- 0xFFFFFFFF (4GB)
|      32-bit      |
|  memory mapped   |
|     devices      |
|                  |
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|                  |
|      Unused      |
|                  |
+------------------+  <- depends on amount of RAM
|                  |
|                  |
| Extended Memory  |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+  <- 0x00100000 (1MB)
|     BIOS ROM     |
+------------------+  <- 0x000F0000 (960KB) 
|  16-bit devices, |
|  expansion ROMs  |
+------------------+  <- 0x000C0000 (768KB)
|   VGA Display    |
+------------------+  <- 0x000A0000 (640KB)
|                  |
|    Low Memory    |
|                  |
+------------------+  <- 0x00000000

In the table above, the space allocated for the BIOS is from 0xF0000 to 0xFFFFF.  The first line of the boot system is at 0xFFFF0, located at the end of the system, and the instruction is ljmp $0xf000,$0xe05b.  The purpose of this instruction is to jump to the first instruction of the BIOS.  This confuses me.  I know that the size of the BIOS can vary between different manufacturers, so the address of the ljmp instruction can also vary.  But why don't we set the first instruction of the BIOS at 0xF0000?  Wouldn't that be more intuitive, and we wouldn't need to jump to a separate address after the ljmp instruction
I would like to know why we don't use the address 0xF0000 as the starting address for all BIOS.

Because not all IBM-PC machines had 64KiB of ROM. As an example some had 40KiB (32-KiB BASIC ROM+8KiB other ROM that started at 0xf600:0000. By choosing the highest position to put an instruction it didn't matter if the machine had 4KiB of ROM or 64KiB+, it was always at the same spot. This design also reduced fragmentation of the address space between ROM and RAM.

In 386 and later x86 CPUs, the first instruction fetched by the CPU is at linear / physical address 0xFFFFFFF0, the last 16 bytes of 32-bit phys addrs.  How can a 32-bit x86 CPU start with reset vector 0xFFFFFFF0 even though it starts in 16-bit real mode? .  If your system actually fetches from 0xFFFF0 (the top 16 bytes of 20-bit physical address-space), it's an 8086 or 186 and doesn't support 32-bit device addresses.  (286 fetched its first instruction from the top 16 bytes of its 24-bit physical address-space.)

A continuation of my first comment. By always placing it at the same address the CPU can always be hardwired to that address at boot up. If you had a 32KiB ROM and wanted to put the entry point at 0xf800:0x0000 (the start) you'd have to modify the CPU to start at that address.You don't want to have to make changes to the CPU itself just because there is a different amount of ROM in the machine. A fixed location at the very top of the 1MiB address space was chosen so the CPU didn't need to be adjusted and differing system ROM sizes could be accommodated.

This address is actually consistent across BIOS implementations.  The address was used in an early BIOS and some programs hard code it.  Later BIOS implementations had to put their code at the same location lest vintage programs won't work.
